# $GLOBALS = array();?

Tags: php

Is there anything problematic in simply setting `$GLOBALS` to be an empty array? I want to reverse the effect of `register_globals` where it is turned on and one does not have access to the `.ini` file, but rather than iterate over each of the relevant super globals and unset where necessary, skipping such elements as `$GLOBALS['_POST']`, `$GLOBALS['_GET']`, etc. as is usually done, I wonder if it's OK to just remove them all.

Are there any problems that may arise from this? I don't ever plan to reference the `$GLOBALS` array as any variables that are to be scope-independent will either be set in the relevant super global (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc.) or will be stored as properties of a relevant registry class.

For information, the FAQ at http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.misc.php#faq.misc.registerglobals has the following to emulate `register_globals = 0`:

```
<?php
// Emulate register_globals off
function unregister_GLOBALS()
{
    if (!ini_get('register_globals')) {
        return;
    }

    // Might want to change this perhaps to a nicer error
    if (isset($_REQUEST['GLOBALS']) || isset($_FILES['GLOBALS'])) {
        die('GLOBALS overwrite attempt detected');
    }

    // Variables that shouldn't be unset
    $noUnset = array('GLOBALS',  '_GET',
                     '_POST',    '_COOKIE',
                     '_REQUEST', '_SERVER',
                     '_ENV',     '_FILES');

    $input = array_merge($_GET,    $_POST,
                         $_COOKIE, $_SERVER,
                         $_ENV,    $_FILES,
                         isset($_SESSION) && is_array($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : array());

    foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
        if (!in_array($k, $noUnset) && isset($GLOBALS[$k])) {
            unset($GLOBALS[$k]);
        }
    }
}

unregister_GLOBALS();

?>
```

Presumably performing `unset($GLOBALS[$k]);` does the same as performing `$GLOBALS = array();` except that the latter removes *everything* and involves only one line of code.

The question then is: is it bad to unset `$GLOBALS['_GET']`, `$GLOBALS['_PUT']`, etc. ("the variables that shouldn't be unset" as the example states -- is this really the case?)?

**Update:**

I've answered this myself below. Silly me for not trying earlier.

Comment: It's recursive at the pointk `$GLOBALS['GLOBALS']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered <strike>part of</strike> this myself. I was stupid for not trying earlier:

```
$var = 'Hello, world!';

unset($GLOBALS['var']);

echo $var; // Notice: Undefined variable: var



$var = 'Hello, world!';

$GLOBALS = array();

echo $var; // Hello, world!
```

So simply setting `$GLOBALS` as an empty array won't unset the global variables. They need to be explicitly unset.

**Update:**

Using `unset($GLOBALS['_GET']);` is the same as using `unset($_GET)` which is definitely not what I want. Question answered.

Answer (score 2):

PHP [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) says

```
$GLOBALS — References all variables available in global scope
```

If the word 'Refernences' is used in the typical PHP way, setting `$GLOBALS=array()` won't help you, you would need:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $k=>$v) unset($$k);
```

**Edit:** This could be expanded to

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $k=>$v) 
  if (substr($k,0,1)!='_')
    unset($$k);
```

just for safety! (Didn't try out)

**Edit 2:**

As from Karoly's comment, if you do this in a class or function, you need

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $k=>$v) {
  global $$k;
  unset($$k);
}
```

**Edit 3 was editied awy**

.. because it contained fat fingers - unexpected result came from a typo!

Comment: That seems to conflict with the FAQ on register globals: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.misc.php#faq.misc.registerglobals - see the second example re. "Emulate register_globals off" where all that's needed is `unset($GLOBALS[$k]);`;

Comment: @MichaelRushton So the word 'references' is NOT used int the common PHP sense, thanks for pointing this out - but look at my update answer!

Comment: @EugenRieck, I believe that's because you manually set `$b`. This is for when `register_globals` is turned on and one can use `$b` to get the value from `$_GET['b']`.

Comment: @MichaelRushton But it shows, that `unset($GLOBALS['blah'])` is definitly different to `unset($blah)`

Comment: Strange. I have `$a = 1; unset($GLOBALS['a']); echo $a;` and am getting "Notice: Undefined variable: a in..."

Comment: Ah, in your example you have `unset($GLOBAL['b']);` rather than `unset($GLOBALS['b']);`

Comment: @MichaelRushton Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa.